# XML parsing with a Class call

Tags: python-3.x, xml, class

I parsed an xml file with `xml.etree` python module. Its Working well, but now I try to call this code as a module/Class from a main program. I would like to send the xml tree and a filename for the csv writing to the Class.

My dummy file to call the file with the Class:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='phonebook.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
from xml2csv import Vcard_xml2csv

my_export = Vcard_xml2csv(tree, 'phonebook.csv')
my_export.write_csv()
```

here is the class:

```
class Vcard_xml2csv:
    """The XML phone book export to a csv file"""
    
    def __init__(self, tree, csvfilename):
        root = tree.getroot()
        self.csvfilename = csvfilename    

    def write_content(contact, csvfilename):
        with open(csvfilename, mode='a+') as phonebook_file:
            contact_writer = csv.writer(phonebook_file, delimiter=',', quotechar=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            contact_writer.writerow([contact]) # delete [] if you will see only text separated by a comma 

    def write_csv(tree):
        for contacts in tree.iter(tag='phonebook'):
            for contact in contacts.findall("./contact"):       
                row=[]
                for category in contact.findall("./category"):
                    print('Category: ',category.text)
                    category=category.text
                    row.append(category)
                    
                   
                for person in contact.findall("./person/realName"):
                    print('realName: ',person.text)
                    realName=person.text
                    row.append(realName)
                
                for mod_time in contact.findall("./mod_time"):
                    print ('mod_time: ', mod_time.text)
                    mod_time=mod_time.text
                    row.append(mod_time)

                
                for uniqueid in contact.findall("./uniqueid"):
                    print ('uniqueid: ', uniqueid.text)
                    uniqueid_=uniqueid.text
                    row.append(uniqueid_)
                    
                    
                numberlist=[]    
                for number in contact.findall("./telephony/number"):
                    
                    print('id',number.attrib['id'],'type:',number.attrib['type'], 'prio:',number.attrib['prio'], 'number: ',number.text)
                    id_=number.attrib['id']
                    numberlist.append(id_)
                    type_=number.attrib['type']
                    numberlist.append(type_)
                    prio_=number.attrib['prio']
                    numberlist.append(prio_)
                    number_=number.text
                    numberlist.append(number_)
                    
                    contact = row + numberlist            
                    write_content(contact, csvfilename)   
                    numberlist=[]
```

Iam geeting the ERROR below:

> for contacts in tree.iter(tag='phonebook'): AttributeError:
> 'Vcard_xml2csv' object has no attribute 'iter' Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we define a method in a class, like `write_csv()` in the example, the first parameter is always the class instance. Think of it as a way to access class attributes and methods. Conventionally, for readability, the first parameter is called `self`.

In the write_csv method, `tree` has become this class instance and that is the reason you see the error. The resolution to this would be to define the method like the following:

```py
def write_csv(self, tree)
    ....
    ....
```

and the call to the method would be:

```py
my_export.write_csv(tree)
```

I hope this helps. More about `self` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/)

Comment: Thank you! Error message put me on the wrong path, With your hints, I could fix it now and it is working now as I expect.